# How to change value on regedit using CMD script?

Tags: regedit

Can someone help me to make a cmd script to change value on 3000 out of 3400 subfolders that the value should be changed to the newest value without impacting the 400 subfolders?

The old dbpassword value is Pass123, the newest value is Pass234.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Myfolder\Mainfolder\BRN3130\Database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/saCZI.jpg

Comment: How is your CMD script supposed to know which of the 3400 it should update and which it should not?

Comment: That's my question as well. Should I change it one by one?

Comment: If you can't figure out how to tell which ones should change and which ones should not yourself, you're certainly not going to be able to figure out how to do so in code. Your first task is to work out the logic to know which to change **without code**, and then you can try to find a way to do it **with code**. But you have to do the first before you can even make an effort to do the second. We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use reg.exe instead of regedit.

reg add /?

```
REG ADD KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve] [/t Type] [/s Separator] [/d Data] [/f]
        [/reg:32 | /reg:64]

  KeyName  [\\Machine\]FullKey
           Machine  Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the
                    current machine. Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote
                    machines.
           FullKey  ROOTKEY\SubKey
           ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
           SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  /v       The value name, under the selected Key, to add.

  /ve      adds an empty value name (Default) for the key.

  /t       RegKey data types
           [ REG_SZ    | REG_MULTI_SZ | REG_EXPAND_SZ |
             REG_DWORD | REG_QWORD    | REG_BINARY    | REG_NONE ]
           If omitted, REG_SZ is assumed.

  /s       Specify one character that you use as the separator in your data
           string for REG_MULTI_SZ. If omitted, use "\0" as the separator.

  /d       The data to assign to the registry ValueName being added.

  /f       Force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt.

  /reg:32  Specifies the key should be accessed using the 32-bit registry view.

  /reg:64  Specifies the key should be accessed using the 64-bit registry view.
```

Reg Add with the /f will help you overwrite an existing value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But how to specify the 3000 subfolders? Can you give the simple of the script?

Comment: The poster appears to be looking for a solution to deciding whether the password should be changed or not in order to automate the process. I don't think this answers that question.